# Having trouble extending divs to the bottom of the page. jsFiddle included

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Having trouble extending the left and right divs to the bottom of the page, no more no less.

Here's my work.
http://jsfiddle.net/qggFz/26/

Thanks,
Dale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your js solution, sir:

```
//Can place js in <head> tag
$(document).ready(function(){
    var remHeight = $('html').height() - $('#top').height();
    $('#left').css('height', remHeight);
    $('#right').css('height', remHeight);
});
```

css:

```
body, html
{
    height: 100%;
}
.top {
    background: red;
}
.left {
    width: 25%;
    background: grey;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    width: 25%;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
}
```

html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="top" class="top">
        <div id="msg">hello</div>
    </div>
    <div id="left" class="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="right">
        right
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zTEhB/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.  Suppose I need to recalculate that if the window gets resized after being loaded?

Comment: @Dale Np. Yeah, you might have to run this whenever the page content is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Check: http://jsfiddle.net/5gqNn/

You need to specify the height of the root element.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/height

> The  is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   containing block. If the height of the **containing block is not
>   specified explicitly, the value computes to auto.** A percentage height
>   on the root element (e.g. ) is relative to the viewport.

Comment: Thanks.  You lead me to my original problem.  The original problem is that the left and right divs now go beyond the page.  How can I prevent this from happening not knowing the height of the top div?  Am I going to need to use javascript?

Comment: @Dale Does it help to add `overflow-y:hidden;` (or `overflow:hidden;`) to your left and right divs?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dNYkz/, updated with Shredders overflow:hidden makes the solution complete. Nice one.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that sometimes the content of the divs will exceed the body size and I'll want the scroll bars then.  Maybe a min-height would work?  I'll play with that but I doubt that'll do it.  I'm getting the feeling I need js.

Comment: You are right of course, really strang actually, but I'm running out of answers on how to do this properly. Btw, if you remove the top div, everything is fine. Maybe that might be a way to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to say that the body and html tags are also 100% like this:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    position: relative;}
.top {
    background: red;
}
.left {
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background: grey;
    float: left;
    height:auto !important; /* real browsers */
    height:100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/

    min-height:100%; 
}
.right {
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    float: left;

}
```

Comment: Thanks. The left and right divs now go beyond the page, which is actually my original problem. How can I prevent this from happening not knowing the height of the top div? Am I going to need to use javascript?  If so, that's all I need to hear.

Comment: if they go beyond the rest of your content you have to add a z-index with a higher value. If you want that the left and right div always be on top you can give them: z-index:9999;

Comment: Why would adding a z-index help?

Comment: it keeps your div's in front of the rest of you context if thats what you need?

Comment: I need the left and right divs to stop at the bottom of the page, preventing scroll bars.  The divs should never overlap, so I shouldn't need a z-index.

Comment: O im sorry then i miss red it. Maybe ´overflow:hidden;´ is a option?